# Passing pointers to dll function with ctypes

Tags: python, pointers, dll, ctypes, libusb

I have a vendor-provided DLL for connecting to a piece of lab equipment. The DLL has a function

```
long search_devices(char **serial_number_list, uint32_t *dev_count)
```

that I'm trying to access from Python. What I've done is

```
import ctypes
usb_dllpath = r"path_to_dll"
usb_dll = ctypes.CDLL(usb_dllpath)

usb_dll.search_devices.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint32)]
usb_dll.search_devices.restype = ctypes.c_long

serial_list = ctypes.c_char_p()

num_devices = ctypes.c_uint32(99)
status_search = usb_dll.search_devices(ctypes.byref(serial_list), ctypes.byref(num_devices))
```

The result is that the first run gives an error `OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000`, doesn't change the number of devices found from 99, and leaves the status of the search as 0 (failures should return negative numbers per the DLL's source code), while also apparently locking up the instrument and making the device not appear in the example GUI. Subsequent runs of the script throw no errors but set the value of num_devices to 0 while still leaving the status as 0.

Is this a problem in my python script due to, for example, a null pointer as indicated by the error? Or should I assume there is something going wrong in the DLL?

The relevant C function in the DLL is below, with #defines replaced by their values (`search_devices` is just a wrapper for `UsbSearchDevices`). The function returns a long to describe whether an error occurred and modifies the list of serial numbers and number of found devices in memory using the pointers I pass in.

```
long search_devices(char **serial_number_list, uint32_t *dev_count)
{
return UsbSearchDevices(serial_number_list, dev_count);
}

long UsbSearchDevicesLV(char *serialNumberList, int *numberDevices)
{
    libusb_device_handle *deviceHandle = NULL;
    int deviceCount = 0;
    uint8_t string_usb[9];
    char *list;
    libusb_device **devList;
    libusb_context *ctx = NULL;
    struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
    int r, i;
    int status = 0;
    ssize_t count;

    list = (char*)malloc(160);
    if (list == NULL) return 0;
    list[0] = '\0';
    r = libusb_init(&ctx);
    if (r < 0) return -12;

    count = libusb_get_device_list(ctx, &devList);
    if (count < 0)
    {
        libusb_free_device_list(devList, 1);
        return -2;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        status = libusb_get_device_descriptor(devList[i], &desc);
        if (desc.idVendor == 0x277C && desc.idProduct == 0x0026)
        {
            status = libusb_open(devList[i], &deviceHandle);
            if (status == 0)
            {
                libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(deviceHandle, desc.iSerialNumber, string_usb, sizeof(string_usb));
                strncat(list, (char *)string_usb, 8 + 1);
                libusb_close(deviceHandle);
                deviceCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    strcpy(serialNumberList, list);

    libusb_free_device_list(devList, 1);
    libusb_exit(ctx);
    free(list);

    *numberDevices = deviceCount;
    return 0;
}
```

The provided example C code that uses these functions has its relevant part below:

```
    device_list = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*128); // 128ports to search
    for (i=0;i<128; i++)
        device_list[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*8);

    status = search_devices(device_list, &num_of_devices);
```

Comment: What you've written seems reasonable, so need more information about the DLL function.  Does it return a `char*` as an output parameter (that's the way you've written it)?  But it seems to be writing to the null pointer (`serial_list`) that you passed by reference.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I added the source code for the DLL function. The actual return is a long, but the real output is stored in `serial_list` and `num_devices`. Are you saying that I instantiated `serial_list` as a null pointer, so attempts to write to the location it's pointing to will fail? If that's the case, that seems like it would explain things; failing at `strcpy` would prevent the following lines freeing the devices. So how would I make `serial_list` not a null pointer?

Comment: There's some inconsistencies in the code.  The first parameter is `char*` in C, but declared as `char**` in Python.  `libusb_device** devlist;` should be `libusb_device*` to be correctly passed to `libusb_open`.  Make sure to compile with max warnings enabled and pay attention to them.  Check that the function works when called from C before calling it from Python.

Comment: I spent a day or so trying to recompile the DLL but wound up giving up as I couldn't get VS to include libusb correctly. The vendor also gave me an example program that calls the function and interestingly seems to be slightly broken. The output is `The following device serials found: 1 : 100024BBP☺Np=☻Enter the number of the port` - junk characters are actually output. But I can't easily recompile the exe for more information, so I'm hoping to do it all in Python.

Comment: My second comment about libusb_device** is incorrect.  I downloaded libusb.h and it does contain `libusb_device***` as the type.  I think I looked at `lib_usbopen` vs. `libusb_get_device_list` and confused them.  I was able to compile your code with libusb.h without warnings.  But the first comment is correct the signatures of your function don't agree.  Let me look at it more closely...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C usage example shows how to call the function.  Below is a test function I used that fills out data as described:

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

API long search_devices(char **serial_number_list, uint32_t *dev_count) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        sprintf_s(serial_number_list[i], 8, "SN%05d", i);
    *dev_count = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code to call it that should work for your DLL as well:

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')

dll.search_devices.argtypes = ct.POINTER(ct.c_char_p), ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint32)
dll.search_devices.restype = ct.c_long

serial_list = (ct.c_char_p * 128)()
for i in range(128):
    serial_list[i] = ct.cast(ct.create_string_buffer(8), ct.c_char_p)

num_devices = ct.c_uint32()
status_search = dll.search_devices(serial_list, ct.byref(num_devices))
devices = serial_list[:num_devices.value]
print(devices)
```

Output:

```
[b'SN00000', b'SN00001', b'SN00002', b'SN00003', b'SN00004']
```

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior as before, unfortunately - access violation writing 0. I agree that there's a mismatch between the prototype/wrapper (I assume you saw that I added it above) and the actual function. It seems to me like your change should take care of that but apparently it hasn't.

Comment: I added the example C code's usage of this search function. My C is rusty but it looks like the device list that's passed in is an array of character pointer pointers. That is, each element is a pointer to a block of memory for an 8-character array, with 128 elements. Is that right?

Comment: Correction, it's a pointer to (the first element of) an array of pointers, each of which is pointing to (the first element of) an array of 8 characters. I'm going to be trying to see how I can make that in ctypes

Comment: That was the information I needed :).  Updating answer...

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks, I learned a lot!

Comment: @ttshaw1 That was a complicated interface.  Cleaner might be a single buffer with null-terminated strings, double-null-terminated on the last one.  Then a single buffer and size could be passed and parsed on return for the strings without multiple allocations.